# AJAX не работает в браузере Mozilla Firefox!

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Добрый день!
У меня вот этот код в джаваскрипте

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "decklist.php",
    data: {data : jsonString}, 
    cache: false,

    success: function(){
        console.log("OK");
    }
});
```

и вот этот код в php

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
```

работают в браузерах Google Chrome и Opera, но не работают в Mozilla Firefox и стандартном браузере Android.
Версии браузеров достаточно новые, никаких дополнений и плагинов типо ADBlock не стоит.
Пробовал менять "POST" на "GET", но не помогало. Пробовал использовать разные версии jquery, тоже не помогает! Джаваскрипт генерируется с помощью php в плагине wordpress. decklist.php находится в той же папке как и должно быть.
Помогите пожалуйста!
Заранее очень благодарен!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

С огромным трудом решил проблему, добавив это:

```
async:false,
```

в ajax запрос.

Comment: "С огромным трудом" Вы замаскировали Вашу проблему, и она рано или поздно вылезет опять. Представьте, что было бы, если бы `$.ajax` действительно не работал в Firefox! Да Internet бы просто взорвался от криков на эту тему. Не говоря уже о том, что `async: false` объявлен устаревшим в jQuery 1.8 - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Answer (score 0):

Проверил следующий код в firefox - все работает, вы случаейно не забыли сделать echo в php скрипте?  библиотека jquery какой версии?.. firefox какой версии?....в firefox включен javascript ?..decklist.php лежит в тойже папке что и html файл?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jsonString = '222';
alert('input_data=' + jsonString);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "decklist.php",
    data: {data : jsonString}, 
    cache: false,

    success: function(data){
        alert('Ok');
        alert('output_data=' + data);
    }
});
</script>
```

код decklist.php

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: echo в php скрипте есть, библиотека jquery такой же версии как и у вас в коде, firefox самой последней версии, javascript разумеется включён, decklist.php в той же папке.